# How to reduce cognitive complexity of a method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to reduce cognitive complexity of the following method. How to do it ? To my point of view, I can't, but I am unexperienced in the matter

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Bean)) return false;
   Bean other = (Bean) obj;
    if (property1== null) {
        if (other.property1!= null) return false;
    } else if (!property1.equals(other.property1)) return false;
    if (property2== null) {
        if (other.property2!= null) return false;
    } else if (!property2.equals(other.property2)) return false;
    if (property3== null) {
        if (other.property3!= null) return false;
    } else if (!property3.equals(other.property3)) return false;
    if (property4== null) {
        if (other.property4!= null) return false;
    } else if (!property4.equals(other.property4)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If this is working properly, your question might be more appropriate (correctly framed) for Code Review.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thus my caveat of "correctly framed" (it's not on-topic here, either). I really wish we had a macro for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java's `Objects.equals` to check equality of fields easily. It will return `true` if both given objects are equal or both are `null`, else `false`.

```
if (this == obj) return true;
if (obj == null || this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
Bean other = (Bean) obj;
return Objects.equals(this.property1, other.property1)
  && Objects.equals(this.property2, other.property2)
  && ...;
```

As an alternative there's Apache Commons [`EqualsBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) which also provides a `reflectionEquals` method that automatically gets all fields from your class and compares them. Though this approach might be slower because of reflection and you have less control over what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Bean` is your own class. You could take `property1`, `property2`, etc and put them into an array. Then your equals becomes:

```
    public boolean equals( Object obj )
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (!(obj instanceof Bean))
            return false;

        Bean other = (Bean) obj;

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
            if (properties[i] == null)
            {
                if (other.properties[i] != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!properties[i].equals( other.properties[i] ))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Which also gives you the flexibility of adding more property values later without having to modify the `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A utility class with a method `equal` accepting getters of the `Bean` properties as varargs may be implemented:

```java
public class Are {
    static <T,R> boolean equal(T x1, T x2, Function<T, R> ... getters) {
        return x1 == x2 || Arrays.stream(getters)
                     .allMatch(get -> Objects.equals(get.apply(x1), get.apply(x2)));
    }
}
```

Then `Bean::equals` may be written like this:

```java
// class Bean
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Bean that = (Bean) obj;
    return Are.equal(this, that, 
        Bean::getProperty1, Bean::getProperty2, Bean::getProperty3, Bean::getProperty4
    );
}
```